# How to check string contains allowed characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to check string contains only letters, numbers and next special symbols: "-", "!", "?", "&", "(", ")", ":", "#"

I tried modifying but without success:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])[- \*\?!:#+()0-9]+$/
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? Your regex looks like a JS regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is on the right track, but you should just put all symbols into a single character class:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9!?&():#-]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess, based on your designed expression is that, maybe you would want to have an expression such as:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[*?!:#+()\s-])[A-Za-z0-9*?!:#+()\s-]+$
```

that must allow digits, letters, and special chars, or maybe not, which then this expression which allows `space`:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9*?!:#+()\s-]+$
```

or this one,

```
^[A-Za-z0-9*?!:#+()-]+$
```

which doesn't allow space, might simply suffice.

---

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GI3Ovy/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[*?!:#+()\\s-])[A-Za-z0-9*?!:#+()\\s-]+$";
final String string = "123\n"
     + "abc\n"
     + "?!*\n"
     + "123abc?!*\n"
     + "123  abc?!*";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```